# Petclinic spring-mvc example not building

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven-2, spring-mvc, aspectj

I just co https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/ and tried to build petclinic.
I did:

- mvn clean install
- mvn eclipse:eclipse

I imported to eclipse but:

```
The import org.aspectj cannot be resolved
```

What are the odds that the `pom.xml` is wrong and I have to add the dependency myself?

Comment: I wonder how you imported your project when you tried with STS because I couldn't reproduce the issue, neither in Eclipse nor in STS when using m2eclipse. I guess you didn't use **Import... > Existing Maven Projects**.

Comment: nope. I did `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and then import it as an eclipse project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known [bug](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MECLIPSE-558) in the maven eclipse plugin.

A simple workaround is to specify the adjtVersion in your POM's maven-eclipse-plugin configuration section (or just update your version :D):

```
<ajdtVersion>none</ajdtVersion>
```

The EclipseClassPathWriter contains the following  code:

```
    // Skip aspectj libraries since they are in the container.
            if ( ( config.getAjdtVersion() != 0 ) &&
               dep.getArtifactId().toLowerCase().indexOf( "aspectj" ) >= 0 )
            {
                return;
            }
```

Comment: Yep, I guess it's related to this. Adding that to my pom didn't fix the issue but adding the jar by hand worked, so I guess you are right.